# Setup openvpn as interface device only

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, interface, tun

I just setup OpenVPN client using [this guide on The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/09/openvpn-setup/)

But now (somewhat as expected) all my traffic is routed through the VPN.

I actually just want to set up the interface device.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Here's the config file:

```
client

dev tun
remote purevpnserver.test 53
proto udp
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
tls-auth Wdc.key 1
ca ca.crt
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20
float
route-method exe
route-delay 2
auth-user-pass
auth-retry interact
explicit-exit-notify 2
ifconfig-nowarn
auth-nocache
```

Answer (score 2):

By adding `route-nopull` to the config file, openvpn would ignore the routes pushed from the server to the client.

Something I found [on the openvpn site](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway)