# Use OpenVPN tun device for specific request

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, tun, policy-routing

I have setup an OpenVPN connection with the `route-nopull` configuration.
So now no special routes have been added to the client's configuration and only a TUN device is created, like so:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:13.0.9.88  P-t-P:13.0.9.88  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:150 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:12498 (12.4 KB)  TX bytes:2520 (2.5 KB)
```

As a result, none of the traffic goes over the VPN by default. Great, because I only need it for certain requests.

And there lies my problem: how do I do that?
I'm mainly going to use this in node.js.

In the next example I create a simple GET request using http.request, but I specify the address currently given to the TUN interface.

```
var http = require('http'),
    url  = require('url');

var options = {
    localAddress: '13.0.9.88',
    hostname: 'www.google.be',
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    port: 80
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Body: ' + chunk);
    });
});

req.end();
```

The problem is: this request never goes through or gets a response.

I also tried a simpler test, just using `ping` over the `tun0` interface to one of Google's servers:

```
 ping -I tun0 173.194.112.24
```

This, again, gives no results.

Fyi: When I setup OpenVPN to create a TAP interface (instead of a TUN one), I get a 'Destination Host Unreachable' error

The netstat info of the vpn's ip:

```
# netstat -rn | fgrep 13.0.9
13.0.9.88      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U         0 0          0 tun0
```

What routes do I have to add to enable this?

Comment: What does `netstat -rn | fgrep 13.0.9` output? What is the IP of the server you're trying to reach?

Comment: Yes, I've added the output above. I've also added a simple `ping` test using the -I interface option. I'm currently just trying to get the google page over the vpn.

Answer (score 2):

After quite a search, I found the answer [on this blog by Georgie Casey](http://www.georgiecasey.com/2013/07/26/how-to-use-overplay-and-other-vpns-as-a-curl-proxy/):

The `no-pull` config stays, but after each connection these routes need to be added:

```
ip route add default via  {{P-t-P-IP}}          dev tun0 table 10
ip rule add from          {{tun0-inet addres}}  table 10
```

Those values you can get, for example, from ifconfig (ips modified):

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:16.0.2.11  P-t-P:16.0.2.11  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:5344 (5.3 KB)  TX bytes:2295 (2.2 KB)
```

Comment: i'm the author of that blog post and I upgraded Debian and got the same error. this fixed it, i'll add to the post

Answer (score 1):

You need add routes for the destinations you want to route via the VPN tunnel, like this:

```
route add <destip> gw <server IP>
```

Where `<destip>` is the destination IP you want to route via the VPN, and `<server ip>`is the IP of the OpenVPN server in the `13.0.9.` network.

By the way, you should not use publicly routable IP addresses in private VPNs. You have to use some of the networks defined in RFC1918.

After seeing your original question [Setup openvpn as interface device only](https://serverfault.com/questions/653447/setup-openvpn-as-interface-device-only) , you should remove the `route-nopull` in your client configuration and remove `push "redirect-gateway def1"` from the server configuration file.

Then you can add:

```
push "route <serverip> 255.255.255.255"
```

to the server configuration file. This tells the server to tell client to route `<serverip>` via OpenVPN server.

Comment: But I don't know the ip addresses I want to request beforehand. Sometimes I want to request a certain resource via the vpn, but not all the time.

Comment: Well, then you need to figure out a way to run the `route` command before you make the requests you want to go via the VPN. The point is, you need to add/remove routing table entries to route the requests the way you like.